# Can not print specifict values from an api response dictionnary (Dango)

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary

i'm ne to Django and APIs and i'm struggling with this for days.
Here's my views.py file :

```
import requests
import os
from pprint import pprint
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):


query_url = "https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main"
params = {
    "state": "open",
}
headers = {
    }
result = requests.get(query_url, headers=headers, params=params)
json_data = result.json()
data = json.dumps(json_data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
t = json.loads(data)
print(type(data))
print(type(t))
context = {
    "t": t,
}
return render(request, "navbar/navbar.html", context)
```

And here's the index.html :

```
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Blockchain Explorer</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            
        </head>

        <body >
            
            <div class="API-response">
                {{ t }}
             </div> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

But when i try to do for example :

```
{{ t["height"] }}
```

i get an error : (TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '["height"]' from 't["height"]')

Please help me and excuse me if it is a dumb question, i'm still a beginner in this framework

Comment: Try `{{ t.height }}`, attributes access, key lookups and index lookups are all performed using a `.` in Django templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the attributes using `.` in templates. Have a look at the accessing method calls [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls). You can try accessing using `t.height`.

Answer (score 0):

Being more explicit about your question
whether your t = items for example

In Views.py
...
context = {
"items": items,
}
return render(request, "navbar/navbar.html", context)

In frontend module
...

```
{% for item in items %}
   <div class="API-response">
       {{ item }}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So I have not enough data for your issue in order to be more helfull but try that and give a feedback. Thanks